# JQuery Confirmation Dialog in ASP.Net

Tags: jquery, asp.net

Is there any Confirmation Dialog that is made from Jquery where I can use it in ASP.NEt?

a confirmation dialog that has a "Yes" or "No", "Ok", "Ok" or "Cancel" button?

and example,  if I click "Ok" button, I can perform a condition in the server code of ASP.net.

another example in the dialog box: "Do you want to save this record to the database?" "Yes" or "No"

Comment: show us what you have done..or what you want to do?? are you going to do CRUD operations or just need confirmation to be send to the server page?

Comment: I will perform a CRUD @Scorpio

Comment: Seems like a simple search would have yielded this for you: http://juiceui.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
           jQuery("#send").click(function () {
            $("#dialog").dialog({
                modal: true, title: 'message', zIndex: 10000, autoOpen: true,
                width: 'auto', resizable: false,
                buttons: {
                    Yes: function () {
                        window.location = '<%=demo\test\data%>?ID=' + Id;
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    },
                    No: function () {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                },
                close: function (event, ui) {
                    $(this).remove();
                }
            });
        });


        $("#cancelSend").click(function () {
            window.location.href = "javascript:history.back();";
        });
    });
```

This is how I am doing...but its an MVC Application. but I am sure you can do it the same way for any asp.net application ....
url is the link of your method or the server page  and ID is any query string that you want to pass..
This logic is inside the yes function so will only exec on yes button click..

Answer (score 1):

Use the [jQuery UI Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/):

```
$(element).dialog({
    buttons : {
        Yes : function () {
            $.ajax({...});
        },
        No : function () {
            $(this).dialog('close');
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: how can i declare here my code in the server side:
Yes : function () {
            $.ajax({...});
        },?

Comment: you can't have server side code on the client.  You need to use Ajax to make a call to the server to run server side code.

Comment: how can I call the server side code in ajax? what should I use?